# Asyncio stops returning response after many requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have a list of many urls and I want to check if they are still active. I found some code on https://realpython.com/async-io-python/ and modified it a little. I am very beginner with asyncio so there might be some messy coding.

```
import asyncio
import re
import csv
import sys
from typing import IO
import urllib.error
import urllib.parse
import json
from log import logger_setup
import pandas as pd

import aiofiles
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from lxml.html import fromstring

global logger
logger = logger_setup('main')

async def fetch(url, session):
    """GET request wrapper to fetch page HTML.

    kwargs are passed to `session.request()`.
    """
    if type(url) != str:
        return  None, 'wrong data format', None

    if url.startswith('http'):
        pass

    else:
        return None, 'wrong data format', None

    resp = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
    asyncio.sleep(15)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    logger.info("Got response [{}] for URL: {}".format(resp.status, url))
    html = await resp.text()

    tree = fromstring(html)
    title = tree.findtext('.//title')
    return html, resp.status, title

async def parse(url, session):
    """Find HREFs in the HTML of `url`."""
    try:
        html, status, title = await fetch(url,session)
        # asyncio.sleep(5)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Exception for {}: {}".format(url, e))
        status = e
        html = None
        title = None

    finally:
        logger.info("{} [{}] {}".format(url, status, title))

        if status != 'wrong data format':
            async with aiofiles.open('~/data/lake/dormant_worker/data/{}/new/results.csv'.format(mode),'a+') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
                await writer.writerow([url, title, status])

        return html, status



async def write_one(url, session):
    """Write the found HREFs from `url` to `file`."""
    html, resp = await parse(url, session)
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open('~/data/{}/new/source_codes/{}'.format(mode, url.replace('/','-')), 'w') as f:
            if html == None:
                await f.write("{}".format(None))
            else:
                await f.write("{}".format(html))
            logger.info("Wrote results for source URL: {}".format(url))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(url, e)

async def crawl_and_write(urls):
    """Crawl & write concurrently to `file` for multiple `urls`."""
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(
                write_one(url, session)
            )
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main(arg):
    global mode
    mode = arg
    df = pd.read_csv('~/data/{}/clearnet_{}.csv'.format(mode, mode))

    urls = df['url']
    asyncio.run(crawl_and_write(urls=urls))

main(sys.argv[1])
```

For approx 12k urls, after querying 2k sites nothing is being returned. Sample of responses looks like:

```
15:57:17,82 main INFO Got response [200] for URL: https://www.zeux.com/
15:57:17,85 main INFO https://www.zeux.com/ [200] Zeux | Zeux - Where money never sleeps
15:57:17,97 main INFO Got response [200] for URL: https://www.spheroiduniverse.io/
15:57:17,103 main INFO https://www.spheroiduniverse.io/ [200] Spheroid Universe
15:57:17,163 main ERROR Exception for https://adenium.io: Cannot connect to host adenium.io:443 ssl:default [Name or service not known]
15:57:17,164 main INFO https://adenium.io [Cannot connect to host adenium.io:443 ssl:default [Name or service not known]] None
15:57:17,164 main INFO Wrote results for source URL: https://www.one.game
15:57:17,165 main INFO Wrote results for source URL: https://mvlchain.io
15:57:17,165 main INFO Wrote results for source URL: https://www.coinzark.com
15:57:17,185 main ERROR Exception for https://treasuredapp.io/: 503, message='Service Temporarily Unavailable', url=URL('https://treasuredapp.io/')
15:57:17,186 main INFO https://treasuredapp.io/ [503, message='Service Temporarily Unavailable', url=URL('https://treasuredapp.io/')] None
15:57:17,197 main INFO Got response [200] for URL: https://swapswop.io/
```

than logs are like that:

```
16:00:57,308 main ERROR Exception for https://etherc.io/#EET-ETH: 
16:00:57,308 main INFO https://etherc.io/#EET-ETH [] None
16:00:57,309 main ERROR Exception for http://xrp2019.com/: 
16:00:57,309 main INFO http://xrp2019.com/ [] None
16:00:57,309 main ERROR Exception for https://ethx2.io/: 
16:00:57,310 main INFO https://ethx2.io/ [] None
16:00:57,310 main ERROR Exception for https://cryptomcafee.com/: 
16:00:57,311 main INFO https://cryptomcafee.com/ [] None
16:00:57,311 main ERROR Exception for https://nydig.com: 
16:00:57,312 main INFO https://nydig.com [] None
16:00:57,312 main ERROR Exception for http://beznal.pk/: 
16:00:57,313 main INFO http://beznal.pk/ [] None
16:00:57,313 main ERROR Exception for https://www.bex500.com/: 
16:00:57,313 main INFO https://www.bex500.com/ [] None
16:00:57,314 main ERROR Exception for https://alphawallet.com/: 
16:00:57,314 main INFO https://alphawallet.com/ [] None
16:00:57,315 main ERROR Exception for https://mkr.tools/:
```

I think maybe google antibot may be triggering such behaviour. What do you think and how to eventually bypass it? Would asyncio.sleep(some_time) make a diffrence? I tired using it but didn't see any changes - or i might by using it wrong.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: nice exception handling xD 16:00:57,309 main ERROR Exception for https://ethx2.io/: `empty`

Comment: You need to **await** `asyncio.sleep(5)` for it to have any effect.

Comment: checking treasuredapp now ... it is under Cloudflare ... but seems like you 're DDOSing it and the site is dead xD

Comment: you could read for example about scrapy AutoThrottle extension here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#topics-autothrottle

Comment: i am using `asyncio.sleep(15)` - is it invoked in wrong place?

Comment: Are you awaiting it? You need `await asyncio.sleep(15)`